# Why Empty universe have to obey the Negative Curvature?

Tags: cosmology, metric-tensor, universe, space-expansion, curvature

For empty universe it seems to me that we can have two solutions.
$$H^2=\frac {8\pi G\epsilon} {3c^2}-\frac {\kappa c^2} {R^2a^2(t)}$$

For an empty universe when we set $\epsilon=0$ we get
$$H^2=\frac {-\kappa c^2} {a^2(t)}$$

since the square cannot be  negative $\kappa$ must be $-1$, $\kappa=-1$

However I think, $\kappa=0$ is also a solution. But in one case $a(t)$ will be a constant, $a(t)=C$ since $\dot{a}(t)=0$,

in $\dot{a}(t)=c/R$ comes when we set $\kappa=-1$, in this case it seems to me that $a(t)=ct/R_0t_0$

Are these statements true? Since in general, empty universe which is also called the Milne universe, described by negative curvature. But cant be also described by a flat space ?

Comment: Yes, of course, but that's just Minkowski spacetime. The interesting question is whether there is another vacuum solution.

Comment: Without the @ address your reply is not delivered to anyone. You cannot assume people are looking only at your question waiting for you to respond. They make a comment and move on. So without a proper address they never see your reply.

Comment: @Javier Whats that mean ?

Comment: @ safesphere:  Pot calling the kettle black? (grin)